# trust region - choice of scaling matrix

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, numerical-optimization

According to many resources, TR algorithms often suffer from bad scaling. The simplest remedy is to use scaling matrix D in following way

\begin{align}
\min_d  \    f + g'd + \frac{1}{2}*d'Bd \\
\text{subject to} \  ||Dd|| <= \Delta ,
\end{align}

where D is diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements.

My question is, how to construct such a matrix? which properties should it fulfill?

Answer (score 4):

JJ Moré's paper [Recent Developments in Algorithms and Software for Trust Region Methods](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-68874-4_11) provides guidance for choosing the diagonal scaling matrix.

He shows that the convergence theorems for trust region optimization still hold provided the diagonal scaling matrices $D_k$ satisfy these properties:

(4.6)     $\left\lVert D_k^{-1} \right\rVert \le \sigma_2$
for some $\sigma_2\gt0$

(4.12)   $\left\lVert x_k-x_m \right\rVert \le \delta_1$, $k=m,\ldots, l$, $\implies \left\lVert D_l-D_m \right\rVert \le \delta_2$ for $\delta_1,\delta_2\gt0$

If $f:R^n \rightarrow R$ represents the optimization problem, he then proposes choosing

(4.13)   $D_k=diag(d_{k,i})$, $d_{k,i}=max(d_{k-1,i}, \left| \partial_{ii}f(x_k) \right|^{1/2})$

I gather the reasoning is

1. It makes the algorithm scale invariant under diagonal linear transformations.
2. If $\left|\partial_{ii}f(x_k)\right|$ is large, then it's likely that $f(x)$ is more sensitive to change in that direction, and therefore it's likely the second order approximation to $f(x_k)$ is less accurate and the search area should be more restricted along the ith coordinate.

Moré's other paper [The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm: Implementation and theory](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0067700) has numerical results comparing different scaling methods. Although the methods are slightly different and specialized to least-squares optimization, they would correspond to these strategies:

1. (Initial) $D_k=\left|\partial_{ii}f(x_0)\right|^{1/2}$
2. (Adaptive) (The method described above)
3. (Continuous) $D_k=\left|\partial_{ii}f(x_k)\right|^{1/2}$

For the problems he tested, his results show that (Adaptive) is the best and (Continuous) is worse than either (Initial) or (Adaptive)